# Calling viewDidLoad in UITextField

Tags: swift, uitextfield, viewdidload

What's the code for calling viewDidLoad in UITextField, I only seem to find mixed answers:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var providerForm: UITextField!
```

// What to insert here to call the viewDidLoad function?

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.viewDidLoad()
    self.blockchain = Blockchain(genesisBlock: genesisBlock)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.generateDummyTransactions()
    self.providerForm = providerForm
    self.destinatorForm = destinatorForm
    self.amountSum = amountSum

func generateDummyTransactions() {



    let transaction = Transaction(from: "Mary", to: "Steve", amount: 20.0, transactionType: TransactionType.domestic)
    let block1 = Block()
    block1.addTransaction(transaction: transaction)
}
```

Comment: `viewDidLoad()` is the lifecycle method of all `UIViewController` and is called automatically. It is not called on any of the views, i.e. for any `UITextField`. Please clarify the requirement.

Comment: I wanted a textfield called in the viewDidLoad(), as I have a send button which will launch app process

Comment: textField called means? Do you want to call any method or anything in textField?

Comment: Sorry, I edited and specified. Basically the app runs a on a print(generateDummyTransaction) function, but the generateDrummyTransaction is called from the viewDidLoad function, that's where I need the textfield input to be loaded when pressing a send button in the UIViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `generateDummyTransactions()` from `sendButton's` `IBAction` method and then fetch the `textField's` `text` there, i.e.

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var providerForm: UITextField!

    @IBAction func onTapSendButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.generateDummyTransactions()
    }

    func generateDummyTransactions() {
        if let text = self.providerForm.text {
            //use text here...
        }
    }
}
```